# How to train sklearn models using tensorflow dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I wonder if I can use a Tensorflow Dataset for training scikit-learn and other ML frameworks.

So, for example, can I take a `tf.data.dataset` for training xgboost, LogisticReg, RandomForest classifier etc?
i.e. Can I pass the `tf.data.dataset` object into the `.fit()` method of these models, for training?

I tried out:

```py
    xs=np.asarray([i for i in range(10000)]).reshape(-1, 1)
    ys=np.asarray([int(i%2==0)for i in range(10000)])
    
    xs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(xs)
    ys = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ys)
    cls.fit(xs, ys)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```sh
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'TensorSliceDataset'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a tf.data.dataset for other ml models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915295/how-to-convert-a-tf-data-dataset-for-other-ml-models)

Comment: Dataset created using `tf.data` can be only used with tensorflow premade estimators, tensorflow custom estimators and `tf.keras` Models. In case you want to use tensorflow datasets with other ML frameworks you need to convert the data into a compatible format, eg: dataframe, array, list, etc. If you want to continue with `tf` you may refer the list of premade estimators [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as_numpy_iterator()` method; from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator):

> Returns an iterator which converts all elements of the dataset to numpy.

Following your example:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

x = list(xs.as_numpy_iterator())
y = list(ys.as_numpy_iterator())

clf = SVC(gamma='auto')

clf.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: I guess the question is regarding, whether dataset created from `tf.data` API used with any other models other than tensorflow estimators or `tf.keras` models

Comment: Yes, @SwapnilMasurekar for this case the format is not compatible with Sklearn models, so you could simply call `as_numpy_iterator()` to return a compatible format for the sklearn models. What are your thoughts ?

Comment: it would definitely work and is a great solution for the inbuilt `tensorflow_datasets` and tfrecord datasets to be used with other Frameworks. But converting a raw data into a `tf.data.dataset` obj and reconverting it to a compatible format is not recommended